# VBA code to Filter data and transfer data to other sheet based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to filter data in I column i.e PDF versions by comparing PDF value=1.4 and that filter data need to copy into Sheet1.
Here I'm getting error as run-time error-424 object required

```
Sub FilterMe()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LstR As Long, rng As Range
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim myWb As Excel.Workbook

    Set myWb = ActiveWorkbook

    var = 1.4

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L20").ClearContents

    Set sh = Sheets("DataSheet")    'set the sheet to filter
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")    'set the sheet to paste

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With sh    'do something with the sheet

        LstR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row    'find last row

        .Columns("I:I").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=PDF.var 'ERROR coming here

        Set rng = .Range("A1:I" & LstR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)    

        rng.Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In the error line you are using `PDF.var` but yo don't have a `PDF` object. Use `Criteria1:=var` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What is Criteria1:=PDF.var?

Also while filtering a single column, the field should always be 1.

```
.Columns("I:I").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=var
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to adopt this little (commented) refactoring of your code:

```
Sub FilterMe()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim var As Variant

    var = 1.4

    Set sh = Worksheets("DataSheet") 'set the sheet to filter
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set the sheet to paste
    ws.Range("L1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).ClearContents '<--| clear "paste" sheet columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty one

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With sh '<--| reference your "copy" sheet
        With .Range("I1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell
            .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=var '<--| filter on referenced range 9th column with 'var'
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<--| if any cell filtered other than headers (which get always filtered) then copy filtered values to "paste" sheet
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @AdityaVarma, did you get through it?